# How to deactivate guides in flutter widgets tree, like the attached image

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image: describing issue]

I need to deactivate flutter widget tree guides like the old version of flutter SDK because it disturbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to:

**Preferences** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **Flutter**

And then unchecking **"Show UI guides for build methods"**

See this image for more: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY9X9.jpg